# How to add 2 parameters in a ternary condition - PHP?

Tags: php

In yang config I a have some parameter like:

```
$application_promo_shipping = true;
$application_promo_engrave = false;
```

I make PHP code with a ternary condition like this:

```
<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?= ($this->config->item('application_promo_shipping')?:"d-none")?>">Free Shipping</p>

<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?= ($this->config->item('application_promo_engrave')?:"d-none")?>">Free engrave</p>
```

If the value is `true` the `"d-none"` class is `hide` so the only text show is `Free shipping`

But how can I make like that with 2 parameters, if shipping and engrave is true I want to call a paragraph like this:

> FREE ENGRAVE & FREE shipping

Because with the code now, I have a lot of space between 1 paragraph to another paragraph if I change the value to `true` in 2 parameters.

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 1):

To your main question here ...

**You CAN use multiple operators in one ternary condition and it will look like this:**

```
$output = ($var1 === true && ($var2 == 2 || $var3 == 3)) ? 'if true' : 'if false';
```

**BUT** i wouldn't recommend it in your case simply because your ternary condition would be one mega-long line very hardly understanable to other programmers. So, ... how would i solve it?

Just rename your configuration values to something more understandable and shorter :), then you can do your ternary operation and the code will look good.

**Approach no. 1:**

```
<?php

    $messages = [
        0 => 'Free Shipping',
        1 => 'Free engrave',
        2 => 'FREE ENGRAVE & FREE shipping'
    ];

    $shipping = $this->config->item('application_promo_shipping');
    $engrave = $this->config->item('application_promo_engrave');
    $message_key = ($shipping && $engrave) ? 2 : (($engrave) ? 1 : 0);

?>

<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo"><?php echo $messages[$message_key]; ?></p>
```

**Approach no. 2:** (not recommended)

```
<?php

    $shipping = $this->config->item('application_promo_shipping');
    $engrave = $this->config->item('application_promo_engrave');

?>

<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?php echo ($shipping) ? '' : 'd-none'; ?>">Free Shipping</p>

<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?php echo ($engrave) ? '' : 'd-none'; ?>">Free engrave</p>

<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?php echo ($shipping && $engrave) ? '' : 'd-none'; ?>">FREE ENGRAVE & FREE shipping</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about it is creating the output based on the two variables and store it in a variable that is an array. If the length is at least 1 or higher, print the paragraph and `implode()` the values with the deliminator `&`.  This way, the paragraph doesn't even get rendered in HTML if both conditions are false.

Using shorter code by ternary operators can be useful - but in this case, it can probably be better to not render the output at all if the condition is true by using a normal `if` statement.

```php
$output = [];
if ($this->config->item('application_promo_shipping')) {
     $output[] = "Free shipping";
}
if ($this->config->item('application_promo_engrave')) {
     $output[] = "Free engraving";
}

if (count($output)) {
    ?>
    <p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo"><?php echo implode(" & ", $output); ?></p>
    <?php
}
```

If you're hell-bent on using a ternary and using the `d-none` class, you can do that as well with the same condition (but you will still need the first two `if` blocks to declare the values of `$output`).

```php
<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo <?= count($output) ?: 'd-none'; ?>"><?= implode(" & ", $output); ?></p>
```

Comment: You made a mistake on lines `$output = "Free shipping";` and `$output = "Free engraving";`, you're missing the empty bracket: `$output[] = "...";`, so the `$output` will be re-typed to a string and the line `count($output)` will probably throw an "Not countable" error.

Comment: Good eye, @CodiMech25! I'll fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a much simpler approach in order to make my code readable to other developers. Nothing worse than having to decipher code where someone has tried to be unnecessarily clever.

**I would do something like this:**

```
if (application_promo_shipping AND !application_promo_engrave) {
    echo '<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo">Free Shipping</p>';
}

if (application_promo_engrave AND !application_promo_shipping) {
    echo '<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo">Free Engraving</p>';
}

if (application_promo_engrave AND application_promo_shipping) {
    echo '<p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo">Free Engraving</p> & <p class="mx-auto nav-link-promo">Free Shipping</p>';
}
```